# Samba - Allow users to change its own password

Tags: ubuntu, security, users, samba

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server with a bunch of users, all having accounts on it and their home directories being available via Samba.

I need to allow each user to be able to change its own Samba password using smbpasswd but it seems that I won't work since I get the following error:

> SAMR connection to machine 127.0.0.1 failed. Error was NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, but LANMAN password changes are disabled

As far as I was able to look for a solution I couldn't find a good one (e.g. using kpasswd instead, using SWAT, etc.)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set "nt pipe support = no" in smb.conf to mitigate wannacry and the rest ...... It BREAKS the ability for the user to change their own password via smbpasswd

Einer

Comment: That's right!I forgot that I had that set it to no and when I looked again in the config file I saw it.

Thank you!